# VBA to extract a unique list from Sheet 1 column N and list on sheet 2 column B based on a condition on sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba, list, unique

Tricky one here as I am not a coding expert.

- On sheet 1 column N I have a list of products
- Sheet 1 column D has the corresponding supplier number for column N products
- Sheet 2 cell B1 has the supplier number.

What I am after is a vba code that runs automatically when the supplier number is selected from the drop down in Sheet 2 cell B1, a unique list in generated from Sheet 1 column N based on a match in the supplier numbers from Sheet 1 column D, and place into B15.

[image: Left hand sheet shows sheet 2 and where I would like stuff exported, RHS shows where the data is located on the report.]

Comment: The layout of `sheet 1` is missing on your screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `Dictionary` object to get the unique product list
- Right click on `sheet2` tab > View Code > paste the code

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.ClearContents method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearcontents?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144095)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Address = "$B$1" And Len(.Cells(1).Value) > 0 Then
            Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
            Dim i As Long, sKey As String, sSupp As String
            Dim lastRow As Long, arrData
            Dim oSht1 As Worksheet
            Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
            sSupp = .Value
            lastRow = oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngData = oSht1.Range("D1:N" & lastRow)
            arrData = rngData.Value
            Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
            For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
                sKey = arrData(i, 1) ' Col D [Supplier]
                If StrComp(sSupp, sKey, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    objDic(arrData(i, 11)) = ""
                End If
            Next i
            ' Write Product list to sheet
            lastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If lastRow > 14 Then Me.Range("A15:A" & lastRow).ClearContents
            If objDic.Count > 0 Then Me.Range("A15").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Update:

> Question: If I was to use the code to transpose a list from a different column, eg column Z, instead of N

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Address = "$B$1" And Len(.Cells(1).Value) > 0 Then
            Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
            Dim i As Long, sKey As String, sSupp As String
            Dim lastRow As Long, arrData
            Dim oSht1 As Worksheet
            Const COL_SUPPLIER = 4 ' Col D
            Const COL_DATA = 14 ' Col N, 26 for Col Z
            Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
            sSupp = .Value
            lastRow = oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, COL_SUPPLIER).End(xlUp).Row
            If COL_DATA > COL_SUPPLIER Then
                Set rngData = oSht1.Range("A1", oSht1.Cells(lastRow, COL_DATA))
            Else
                Set rngData = oSht1.Range("A1", oSht1.Cells(lastRow, COL_SUPPLIER))
            End If
            arrData = rngData.Value
            Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
            For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
                sKey = arrData(i, COL_SUPPLIER) ' Col [Supplier]
                If StrComp(sSupp, sKey, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    objDic(arrData(i, COL_DATA)) = ""
                End If
            Next i
            ' Write Product list to sheet
            lastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If lastRow > 14 Then Me.Range("A15:A" & lastRow).ClearContents
            If objDic.Count > 0 Then Me.Range("A15").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do I paste this on sheet 1 code, sheet 2 code?  I get lost with private subs

Comment: It's the event code for sheet 2.

Comment: Posted into sheet one, changed the drop down but no items transferred across :(

Comment: Have you seen my last comment and updated answer? It's for sheet2.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say sheet 2

Comment: Restart Excel or run `Application.EnableEvents = True` in VBE immediate window, then test the code again.

Comment: Restarted excel. tried again, but no joy. manually typed a few test lines into A15 where the output list starts, when I change the dropdown it clear existing content, just not populating

Comment: It means change event is activated. But there isn't matched supplier on sheet1. Please try the updated code.

Comment: Appears to have worked thank you very much legend. Been googling this for weeks. Really appreciate your help

Comment: No. I've revised the code. You can change `Const COL_DATA = 14 ' Col N, 26 for Col Z` to get the expected outpu.

Comment: Sorry to add another variable to this, is there a way to have it so if I change the value in B1 it lists the data as per the above code, but if I had another drop down in in B2 it would take both values into consideration when outputting the list?  Also is there a way to have this activate if the values in B1 and B2 are from a vlookup from a data validation list?  It appears that at the moment it has to be manually typed in.

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) You'll get the support from SO users.